# Individual licenses needed for guests on 2012 datacenter?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012, licensing, datacenter

I think I may not be 100% clear on Microsoft's licensing model for Server 2012 Datacenter edition.

I have read that datacenter entitles you to run unlimited VMs, but Standard only allows you to run 2. Is this merely an entitlement, meaning I would still need a standard license for the guest VM, or does it mean that a datacenter license "Licenses" me to run unlimited VMs, meaning I don't need individual licenses for guest VMs.

Hopefully the former, probably the latter.

Comment: Not going to VTC this since it is easily answerable, but it should probably fall under the canonical "Licensing" question: http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue

Comment: I understand this may be a simple question, and could fall under the topic of the post, but this is a general question about a specific microsoft product, and not specific to my organisation or hardware needs. I am just trying to understand if "running unlimited" is the same as "run unlimited without needing to buy licenses for the VMs"

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. Are you asking whether or not you need separate product keys for the VM's?

Comment: Yes essentially. So if I had a machine and ran 10 VMs on it, I would need one license for the actual machine, and then 10 licenses for the VMs.

Comment: @Eds - I get your question just fine.  I'm stating that 99% of the time SF will close ANY licensing question because the answers given don't come straight from the OEM's mouth and therefore should only be guidance/opinion.  That's why we almost always close licensing questions and refer the OP to ask the OEM or their VAR.  I didn't vote to close this one though, because Ryan Ries easily answered it with authoritative reference.

Comment: OK fair enough, that is understandable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/D/4/3D42BDC2-6725-4B29-B75A-A5B04179958B/WindowsServer2012VirtualTech_VLBrief.pdf

> For customers that want to have a highly virtualized environment,
>   Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter edition is the right edition to use.
>   Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter edition will allow you to run
>   unlimited virtual instances with each license on a single server. This
>   allows you to grow as much as you need to, and with no limit there is
>   no need to track how many instances you are running to ensure that you
>   are compliant.

Also, read up on Automatic Virtual Machine Activation (AVMA), new to Server 2012:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn303421.aspx

> Practical Applications [of AVMA]
>
> On virtualization servers that are activated using Volume Licensing or
>   OEM licensing, AVMA offers several benefits.
>
> Server datacenter managers can use AVMA to do the following:
>
> • Activate virtual machines in remote locations
>
> • Activate virtual machines with or without an internet connection
>
> • Track virtual machine usage and licenses from the virtualization
>   server, without requiring any access rights on the virtualized systems
>
> There are no product keys to manage and no stickers on the servers to
>   read. The virtual machine is activated and continues to work even when
>   it is migrated across an array of virtualization servers.
>
> Service Provider License Agreement (SPLA) partners and other hosting
>   providers do not have to share product keys with tenants or access a
>   tenant’s virtual machine to activate it. Virtual machine activation is
>   transparent to the tenant when AVMA is used. Hosting providers can use
>   the server logs to verify license compliance and to track client usage
>   history.

Comment: Thanks for this, I like the sound of AVMA. However, my concern is it still doesn't seem to 100% answer my question. As quoted, it says "Datacenter edition will allow you to run unlimited virtual instances" it does not seem to clarify if these instances then need to be separately licensed. I read it as though standard will let you actually RUN 2 virtual instances, but datacenter allows you to RUN unlimited. Am I being dense or does it still seem a bit vague? Surely you would need seperate licenses and keys to activate the virtual machine without AVMA?

Comment: You get keys, the only issue is when you want to run older OSs, etc when activation gets in the way of your entitlement.

Comment: To clarify: Automatic Virtual Machine Activation (AVMA) is available in Windows Server 2012 R2, not Windows Server 2012, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

With the datacenter edition you can run unlimited Windows 2012 VMs, *but* you're only licensed for a 2 physical cpu server.
For example, if you have a 4 cpus server, you need to pay for 2 licenses.

See http://download.microsoft.com/download%2F4%2FD%2FB%2F4DB352D1-C610-466A-9AAF-EEF4F4CFFF27%2FWS2012_Licensing-Pricing_FAQ.pdf

The breakdown point between datacenter and standard editions come more or less when you need to host over 5 virtual machines per 2 cores.

Comment: Thanks, but as per Ryan's answer and my comment, running unlimited instances/VMs doesn't tell me whether that means they are also licensed? My Windows 8.1 PC can run seemingly unlimited VMs using Hyper-V, but they aren't licensed. Sorry if I am missing the point.

Comment: This is the difference between a feature and a licence. The feature allows you to run unlimited VMs on any version of hyper-v/virtual pc but you need licences to cover them.  The licence with datacenter grants you permission to run unlimited copies of windows as VMs, hence they are licenced.